# VSCode: Running output with F8 on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: visual-studio-code, output

I'm used to press F8 on VSCode to run simple JS codes that doesn't need Live Server to visualize everything. But now I'm on a course that uses VSC on Ubuntu, and this doesn't work. I think this is a PowerShell feature, which Ubuntu doesn't have. Is there a workaroud so I don't have to open Chrome output for every little piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is an extension called Node.js Exec. I just found it looking back at old material I have. It'll run your JS files when you press F8 on the VSC Output tab.